# Unable to fetch maven dependencies from company's nexus repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, maven-3

I am trying to build Spring Boot application which has several dependencies residing on maven public and company's Nexus Repository. But I get below error every time, I am trying to resolve the dependencies:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:4.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.2 -> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-verifier:jar:4.0.2 -> com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert:jsonassert:jar:0.6.2 -> com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0 -> org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:[2.0.0,) @
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:4.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.2 -> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-verifier:jar:4.0.2 -> com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert:jsonassert:jar:0.6.2 -> com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0 -> org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:[2.0.0,) @

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:389)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:349)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.xxx.xxx:XXXXXXXX:2.0.${revision} (<PATH_TO_PROJECT>\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:4.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.2 -> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-verifier:jar:4.0.2 -> com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert:jsonassert:jar:0.6.2 -> com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0 -> org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:[2.0.0,): No versions available for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:[2.0.0,) within specified range -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Plugin org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:4.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.2 -> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-verifier:jar:4.0.2 -> com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert:jsonassert:jar:0.6.2 -> com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0 -> org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:[2.0.0,)
```

Surprisingly other developers in my team are able to fetch the dependencies without a glitch. In fact, the settings.xml is also same for all of us!!

Comment: Depending on the Nexus version and its settings, older versions of dependencies get deleted automatically from the repo. Maybe the other developers in your team have the required versions in their local cache/repo while you don't - and because they're not on Nexus, you get the error message. Wild guess though (based on a true story).

Comment: Based on this `.${revision}` you are using ci friendly but have not used flatten-maven-plugin correctly please check the docs about it (https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the core issue. Actually, I had open my settings.xml file on 3 different editors which was getting overridden while I was doing the maven clean install. This inconsistency of file was throwing up this issue!!